# Symfony services.yaml handle exception

Tags: symfony, autowired

In my `services.yaml`, I'm having this code:

```
services:
    # prepare database
    DatabaseProvider:
        class: Kepler\Providers\DatabaseProvider
        arguments: ['%database.reader.dsn%', '%database.reader.username%', '%database.reader.password%']

    ReaderPDO:
        class: PDO
        factory: ['@DatabaseProvider', generateDatabaseConnection]

    WriterPDO:
        class: PDO
        factory: ['@DatabaseProvider', generateDatabaseConnection]
```

And DatabaseProvider:generateDatabaseConnection

```
public function generateDatabaseConnection() {
        try {
            return new PDO($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return new PDO($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);
            $_GLOBALS['db_error'] = true;
        }
    }
```

So my question is here: There will be cases where the PDO connection is not working/failing. So how I catch this exception and return the general 404 page (This is the page where I don't need any db connection)?

Some basic analysis:

- I believe this is failing during symfony booting up
- Even if I return null, or return nothing in the catch, the code will keep continue **autowiring**, which will then fail in Controller that requires DB connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having a `return` in a `catch` block should be considered harmful if it's *exactly the same thing* to be returned as in the `try` block.

Setting a global value is really old-school and not really the symfony way. Instead, you would throw a specific exception (or just not catch the PDO one), and add an event listener for the [kernel exception](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-exception) that will result from that, where you may look for that specific exception and return the proper error page you want.

If you just want the 404 page, you can throw the [`NotFoundHttpException`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Exception/NotFoundHttpException.php) or maybe more appropriate the [`ServiceUnavailableException`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Exception/ServiceUnavailableHttpException.php) ...

Comment: Oh, when I read about kernel exception, I thought it's just a Twig Rendering error. I don't know it can be used for other things

Comment: kernel exception is essentially when the server returns an error (like 404, access denied, ... or an actual server error) and there is an ExceptionController buried deep, that will use twig to render an error page if an exception is thrown. But you can intervene and do your own stuff or implement your own exception controller.

Comment: I will definitely give it a go. Thanks